# How can I use special input format in Highcharts?

Tags: highcharts

I have an input, which you can see below:

```
{
    "Data": [{
        "Time": "00:00:00",
        "Value": 2959.927000
    }, {
        "Time": "00:15:00",
        "Value": 2959.927000
    }, {
        "Time": "00:30:00",
        "Value": 2959.927000
    }, {
        "Time": "00:45:00",
        "Value": 2959.927000
    }, {
        "Time": "01:00:00",
        "Value": 2959.927000
    }, {
        "Time": "01:15:00",
        "Value": 2959.927000
    }]
}
```

I would like to display it, how can I?

Comment: I found this: http://karanbalkar.com/2014/06/populate-highcharts-with-json-data-using-jquery/
It is almost good, but I don't know how do I set up the xAxis type?

Comment: You need to convert your json to correct form. it should be x and y values and time should be timestamp (time in miliseconds).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the script you found at http://karanbalkar.com/2014/06/populate-highcharts-with-json-data-using-jquery/ and then just modify the part where you populate the series:

```
// Populate series
for (i = 0; i < data.student_data.length; i++) {
    processed_json.push({
        name: data.student_data[i].key,
        y: parseInt(data.student_data[i].value)
    });
}
```

Then, you set the `xAxis` type to category:

```
xAxis: {
    type: 'category'
}
```